What proportion of Supreme Court decisions are on the substance of the underlying claim, as opposed to technicalities?
In the recent  decision on FOOD AND DRUG ADMINISTRATION ET AL. v.
ALLIANCE FOR HIPPOCRATIC MEDICINE ET AL (the mifeprestone case), the Supreme Court ruled against the Alliance on the grounds that they didn't have standing. So they didn't actually make any decision regarding FDA's approval of mifesprestone, and no precedent was set regarding FDA's regulatory processes. While this maintains the status quo regarding availability, it leaves the door open for future challenges by other groups that may actually have standing.
An example where they did decide on the substance is Garland v. Cargill. There, the question was whether adding a "bump stock" to a rifle turns it into a machine gun, which can then be outlawed per the National Firearms Act of 1934. SCOTUS decided that it doesn't, so bump stocks are legal.
And in Trump v. United States, where the question was about the President's immunity, they did rule on this issue: POTUS enjoys almost total immunity for official acts, and a presumption of immunity for many other actions.
I think many citizens expect SCOTUS to be the final arbiter of constitutionality, as they were in decisions like Brown v. Board of Education (school segregation), Loving (interracial marriage) and Obergefell (same-sex marriage), but I feel like these are the exception, not the rule. This left me wondering: Is there a database of SCOTUS decisions that characterizes them based on whether they were decided on the substance of the original case versus technicalities like standing, statute of limitations, etc.? If so, what are the relative proportions?

precedent was set: The org does not have standing, and neither does another org that is set up similarly..

But no precedent was set regarding the issue they sued over.

I think the point of my question is clear, but I've worded it poorly. Feel free to edit to express it properly.

I don't really care much about those. I only care about cases where they avoided deciding the issue of the case that was appealed.

For example, in the very case you cite, the literal question presented, as worded in the Court's order granting certiorari, said: "Whether an association can demonstrate Article III standing to enjoin a government
action by arguing that some unspecified member may be injured at some future time by the challenged action." The "technicality" was the first question they set out to answer.

There are 2 questions there: 1 is standing, 2 seems to be the merits; I guess 2 becomes moot when because of the decision on 1.

I understand. Maybe I'm just naive in thinking that most cases are appealing the merits rather than technicalities like this. We think of SCOTUS as deciding on weighty constitutional issues, there's nothing consitutional about standing.

As an example, I think the bump stock case was decided on merits -- they decided that adding a bump stock doesn't cause the gun to become a machine gun, so the law banning them doesn't apply.

I think a finding of lack of standing can sometimes be a technicality (if the behaviour at issue harms somebody else who would have standing if they sued for the same thing, and the court would then have to rule on the merits) but also can often be interpreted as ruling on the merits (e.g. if the behaviour harms nobody, and therefore nobody would have standing to sue, a finding of no standing is in some way upholding that the behaviour itself is OK).

@Jen I think the word I should be using is substance -- I want to know which cases they ruled on the substance of the original case. In the case of mifeprestone, the original case was about whether FDA followed proper procedures when they set their rules about how mifeprestone could be prescribed. A lower court ruled that FDA did not have that authority. SCOTUS never addressed that decision, because they ruled that the original case was moot due to lack of standing.

So we still don't know the answer to the original question.

"Is there a database of SCOTUS decisions that characterizes them based on whether they were decided on the substance of the original case versus technicalities like standing, statute of limitations, etc.? " No. Not a comprehensive and publicly available one anyway.


What proportion of Supreme Court decisions are on the substance of the
underlying claim, as opposed to technicalities?

Many, but it is hard to quantify.
Standing comes up in a very large share of public law cases (i.e. non-criminal cases with a governmental party). Also, often cert is granted with respect to technical aspect of a lawsuit, rather than core issue in the lawsuit on the merits (the case cited in the OP is one such case).
Indeed, there is a principle of appellate law, not always followed by SCOTUS, that cases should be decided on the narrowest ground possible, deferring the merits of a central issue to the greatest extent possible, and only deciding those issues if there is no other way to resolve the case. Constitutional issues are supposed to be reached only as a last resort.
It isn't clear where that kind of case would lie within the context of this question.
As a practical matter, however, this is hard to quantify due to definitional issues.
When is a case decided on the substance rather than technicalities?
What constitutes the substance and what constitutes a technicality is very fluid and is somewhat in the eyes of the observer.
Even apart from the definitional issue, there simply isn't a good database, at least not one that is publicly available, which breaks down SCOTUS case decisions on this basis. The corpus of SCOTUS decisions isn't terribly large (50-150 cases a year for 248 years, and you could focus on the modern cases by some measure), but you'd still have to sift though, classify, and count cases from a set of several thousand cases. It is the sort of project that a law professor and a couple of research assistants might spend an entire year working on in order to report their findings in a law review article. If you wanted a quick and dirty first approximation answer, you could look at say, three years worth of decision as a sample of the whole corpus, and maybe finish the project in a few weeks.

I think many citizens expect SCOTUS to be the final arbiter of
constitutionality

This is one thing that SCOTUS does, but not the only or primary role of SCOTUS. In this case, even the underlying merits of the case, as opposed to the standing issue upon which cert was granted and decided, is not a constitutional issue. It is an issue of statutory interpretation for a federal statute.

The substance is the issue that the original case was about. E.g. whether FDA followed legal procedures when they modified their rules on mifeprestone, or whether a rifle with a bump stock is subject to laws against fully-automatic weapons.

"Technicality" often equals "I don't like this outcome."  "Technicality" in the 70's meant Bill of Rights issues.

@TigerGuy While that may often be the case, I think that's disingenuous. I didn't like the OJ decision, and everyone knows that he actually did it, but I believe that it was because the prosecution simply didn't do a good job making their case, there was no technicality involved (like evidence that couldn't be admitted).

@TigerGuy And I think SCOTUS made bad decisions in the bump stock and Trump immunity cases, but these were ideological problems.

The SCOTUS (especially current SCOTUS) often uses "technicality" (e.g.: standing) to avoid deciding on the merits in the way that contradicts their personal convictions. For example, they decided against Prop 8 on technicality, this mifeprestone decision, etc. But they don't shy away from reaching decisions they want even if there's absolutely no constitutional basis for it (Trump's immunity, overturning Roe v. Wade, overturning Chevron, etc). Ultimately it seems that they're just rate-limiting their abuse of power.

I've updated the question, I hope if clarifies the definitional issue.

"there simply isn't a good database" There are organizations like ScotusBlog that track the activity of SCOTUS. I was thinking that one or more of them might categorize things in a useful way.

@Barmar SCOTUS blog categories cases in different ways, but not this particular one.

It was an example (the only resource I've heard of), I hoped there might be others that experts like you could reference.

The issue is not technicality v substance, it’s law v fact
All appellate cases in common law jurisdictions only review the applicable law, not the specific facts of the original case. In theory, if a judge or jury decides a fact incorrectly, or more accurately, in a way the appellate court would not have decided it, then it is not open to the appellate court to overturn the factual decision of the lower court.
Of course, it’s not always clear cut when a decision is one of fact and one of law and legal scholars acknowledge that there are questions that are mixed fact and law.
Some cases may turn on factual issues and some may turn on legal issues. For example, let’s assume that the law says it’s illegal to pass a certain point on a red light. One particular case may turn on whether the light, that everyone agrees is red, was illuminated - that’s a question of fact and, providing evidence was advanced such that the court could draw whatever conclusion it did, is unreviewable. A different case may turn on whether the LEDs the light used are, in fact, red. If “red” is defined in the statute, then this is a factual question, but if “red” isn’t defined, the excat colour of the light is factual, but whether that colour is red or not is legal, that is, the exact shade is a factual question not open to review, whether that shade is red is a legal question.
Now, in the red light example, the legal issue would be substantive, but many legal issues aren’t. Such as whether a particular litigant has standing.

But if the ruling is that the person who brought the lawsuit doesn't have standing, they don't have to decide on law vs. fact (except insofar as there may be a law regarding who has standing, but that's not the claim in the original lawsuit).

But I do understand the point you're making. Many SCOTUS decisions are about what the law or Constitution means, and those are the "law" cases I'm wondering about. That's the substance.
